# Figure Border and title

Tags: graphics, boxes

Hello how can i do lik this border and title to the figure.

```
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{center}
 %% Ici je « lis » LogoMinesNancy.jpg
\includegraphics[height=9.5cm,width=16cm]{oragni}
\end{center}
\caption{
 Présentation d'organigramme }
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`. Please provide compilable code if you want more help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple example adapted from `tcolorbox` [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox), be sure to check. You might want to adjust the title sep and so on...

To change the rounded corners use `sharp corners=all` , and to make the border thinner use `boxrule=0.5pt`. Following *Torbjørn* advice, I've included the `center` option.

Next time please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe). That makes easier for others to reproduce your issue, and find a solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{float=htb,capture=hbox,
center,
colback=white,attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},sharp corners=all,boxrule=0.5pt,colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,boxed title style={size=minimal,toprule=0pt},enhanced,title={#2},every float=\centering,#1}

\begin{document}


\begin{myfigure}{A tcolorbox figure}
\includegraphics[height=9.5cm,width=16cm]{example-image}
\end{myfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have edited the code for border and corner. The rest is up to you, dig the package manual and give it a try. This is a fairly easy package to use, just take some trial'n'error. :)

If this answer your question please remember to check the green `V` as accepted.

Comment: I have another problem is that if the image is large the distance between the left border of the page and much larger than the right part of the distance between the image and the border of the page

Comment: @YacineChamane I dont have that issue, can you please edit the question with an image showing this?

Comment: =========={=======Image======}====

Comment: @YacineChamane If the frame is wider than the textblock it will extend into the right margin. You haven't said anything about your page layout, but 16cm is certainly wider than the default textblock in the `report` class used by G. Bay, and you have some padding between the frame and image in addition. The natural thing to do would be to reduce the width of the image. If you want the figures centered on the page regardless of width, add the `center` option to the `myfigure` (i.e. write `center,` before `float=htb`).